# Joint probabilities of $A$ and independent $B$ and $C$

Tags: probability

> Given that $B$ and $C$ are independent, when would $$P(A\cap B\cap C) = P(A\cap B)P(A\cap C)\;?$$

Comment: A, B, C are three `events` or `logical statements`. comma represents `logical and` or `conjunction`. P(X) represents `probability that statement X is true`.

Comment: Probably it requires that B and C never happen at the same time. If that is the case, the intersection of A, B, and C is same as the union of the (intersection of A and B) and the (intersection of B and C). wait... my brain is not working today.

Comment: That would require either $B$ or $C$ to be impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$P(A\cap B\cap C) =  P(B\cap C)P(A|B\cap C) = P(B)P(C)P(A|B\cap C) $$
Since $$ P(A\cap B)P(A\cap C) = P(B)P(A|B)P(C)P(A|C)$$
we get $$\boxed{P(A|B\cap C) = P(A|B)P(A|C)}$$